# "Tarifa de precios": ¿correcto o redundancia?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

El otro día vi en una bolera un cartel titulado "**Tarifa de precios**", con la lista de lo que costaban cada partida según el día, el alquiler de zapatos y esas cosas.
Me chocó un poco, porque estoy acostumbrado a ver solamente "**Tarifas**" como sinónimo de "lista de precios".

Consultando el DLE veo:

> [**tarifa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZCKWPFd)
>   Del ár. hisp. *ta‘rífa*, y este del ár. clás. *ta‘rīfah*, de *ta‘rīf* 'definición'.
>
> 1. f. Tabla de precios, derechos o cuotas tributarias.
> 2. f. Precio unitario fijado por las autoridades para los servicios públicos realizados a su cargo.
> 3. f. Montante que se paga por un servicio público.

Es decir, que según el DLE, decir "tarifa de precios" vendría a ser como decir "tabla de precios de precios" lo cual es redundante.

Pero si busco literalmente "tarifa de precios" en Google, me salen muchos resultados de medios supuestamente serios, diccionarios de finanzas y demás; verbigracia:

> [**Tarifa de precios**](http://www.expansion.com/diccionario-economico/tarifa-de-precios.html)
>   1. Lista de precios de un establecimiento o servicio. Normalmente la fija cada uno libremente, a menos que se trate de servicios regulados, para los que la Administración fija unas tarifas máximas.

**¿Es correcto este uso? ¿Es algo técnico o lo habéis visto usar en más sitios?** Entendiendo por "correcto" que no haya ninguna pronunciación en contra de la RAE, ni el típico artículo de Fundéu *Tarifas, mejor que tarifa de precios* ni cosas así.

Comment: Para mi es totalmente redundante y me suena mal. Aunque la forma en singular tampoco la uso nunca con la primera definición, en ese caso siempre en plural

Comment: es un total PLEONASMO !!!, igual que salir para afuera

Comment: También me parece redundante, pero parece que es muy común.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la RAE tras la pertinente consulta efectuada, no tiene por qué ser redundante. La definición de *tarifa* dice que la tabla puede ser de precios, sí, pero también de derechos o de impuestos. Así pues, es válido especificar qué tipo de tarifa es la que se muestra mediante un complemento. Esto hace que la combinación *tarifa de precios* no sea redundante.

Si se hace una búsqueda de "tarifa de precios" en Google, el día que se escribió esta respuesta la búsqueda arrojaba 2,14 millones de resultados, lo que la convierte en una expresión bastante común.

Comment: No me convence. Seria más logíco ponerle apellido cuando no fuera una tabla de precios ya que lo normal es que sea de precios, creo que es lo que entiende casi todo el mundo cuando hablamos de *tarifas". Aun así si es de impuestos al final tambien son precios en cierta forma, o al menos una cantidad de dinero, lo de derechos no sé a que se refiere la verdad. Otro tema es que se use mucho y sea un concepto válido (y redundante).

Comment: @blonfu no sería la primera vez que no estamos de acuerdo con una respuesta de la RAE. :-)